# Firestore GET all Boolean TRUE then append FALSE values

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need a request/ request flow that retrieves all the documents where the boolean is true and then gets all that is false.

Is there a firestore query I can make that does this? An orderBy?

Currently, I have an InfiniteScroll and I am struggling for the display to switch between getting true values to getting false values.

```
    if (res.data.length < ITEMS_PER_PAGE) {
        if (onlyListed) {
          // transition from true to false
          setLastVisible(null);
          setOnlyListed(false);
        } else {
          // already transitioned so no more true or false values
          sethasMore(false);
        }
     }
```

It seems the issue is currently it doesn't switch between getting true to false seemlessly on ReactJs side. So a firestore query that fetches all true then false would be perfect as then I can use a regular pagination flow that I know works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the documents where the `onlyListed` field value is `true`, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries):

```
ref.where('onlyListed', '==', true)
```

If you want all documents with the `onlyListed` field, no matter its value, but with them grouped by their value, you can use an [ordered query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#value_type_ordering):

```
ref.orderBy('onlyListed')
```

If this gives the wrong order, you can reverse it by:

```
ref.orderBy('onlyListed', 'desc')
```